# How to ask for a raise as a software developer purely based off accomplishments?

Tags: negotiation, raise, manager

I'm a young developer with a couple years experience. It's not much but I'm always striving to learn more and doing so I know more than many of the senior developers I've worked with when it comes to current technologies and practices; however, that is not always the case.
Out of 4 developers in a project, I've implemented about 30-40% of the infrastructure and functional requirements in our system.

I would like a big raise (15%+) because it bothers me that I'm getting paid *roughly* half of what the other developers get with 6 figure salaries.

How do I convince my manager? He knows the value I bring in to the team but he comes from a large corporation where years of experience is a key factor. I would like to get compensated based on merit and skill rather than experience.

Comment: Find an offer from another company then talk to the manager about possible resignation... then you will see what's what

Comment: Remember that if a company can get away with paying you less than you're worth, they will. It needs to be a realistic outcome to them that you might leave if you don't a raise (and that needs to bother them). So +1 on d'alar'cop's comment - See what else is out there, and what kind of offers people will give you.

Comment: _so I know more than many of the senior developers I know_ : How do you know that? Have you tested them on everything? They may know about many things that you've never had to deal with, so you don't know enough to ask about them, or evaluate properly their knowledge. Also realize that experience accumulates and has value, even if it seems to you that it's not directly translated into hands-on knowledge. It's very common for a young, bright person to fall into the sort of mistake you might be making.

Comment: @Vector. I reworded it a bit. It sounded condesending. Maybe it's the area I'm in, but I haven't had the chance to meet many senior developers with more relevant knowledwge when it comes to modern development. 
You could say that I've tested them, by observing code that violates the SOLID principles and standards.
There is a level of expertise and quality that floats around in StackOverflow that is a total disconnect from the quality I've seen. 
(not always the case though)
I understand I have MUCH to learn, especially when it comes to business experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Collect some facts!**

Get some facts about what you did for your current employer.

**If** you asked previously what you would have to do for a raise. Compare your performance to what you should have done for a raise and look if you qualify. If you do qualify, get a meeting with your boss and present those qualifications and what else you did that's showing extra effort or more performance. Tell your manager that you think you're an asset to your team, you fullfilled the qualifications your boss set in order to qualify for a raise and that you'd like a raise.

If you didn't ask what you would have to do for a raise. Collect facts about how you perform well and you about you putting in the extra effort as opposed to your job description. **Keep it personal!** You don't want to say: "Hey, I am doing better than X, so I deserve a raise.", because you do not know for sure what his qualifications are. Tell him you think you deserve a raise because of your performance. If that's not enough ask him what has to be done in order to qualify for a raise. Doing this will at least give you the information needed in order to qualify for a raise next time.

Answer (score 1):

Convince your boss that you are worth 15% more salary. You say he comes from a large corporation. Promotions and salary raises in big corporations don't come from the years people worked there, you have to list accomplishments outside of the scope of your role. "Because I earn less than my colleagues" is not a good argument.

Numbers are important here. How much time is saved by your implementations? Were your implementations expected from you, or did you go that extra mile to make them better. Was it your initiative, or did you get the task from someone? Does the company earn more money and can you prove that your changes caused that? Was there a quality/cost improvement for the customer? Can you show that you used the resources given to you effective, including your team members? Can you show that you are a team player that can get into a "flow" with colleagues, and therefore be much more productive than working alone?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the salary is depending on the work employee has done for his company and not base on his past experience. Most of the time much experience workers have to do much work load and have much responsibilities thus they are getting higher salaries than new workers.

Let's turn back to your issue. I think it is depending on the system that you have developed.  For example if it is not much complex system I think it is better to wait until your team and supervisor find out that you are valuable worker for the company.

If they already understood you are valuable for them do not hesitate to talk to your manager about the  matter. For example I think it is good time to talk about it, after your supervisor appreciate any of your work.

As d'alar'cop suggested above you can try  higher salary job offer and after you get any go to your supervisor and discuss about the demand.

Comment: Yes, it's really just a matter of establishing what the market rate for "your brand" truly is then using that as leverage (or if you find you're overpaid to keep quiet), simple game-theory really

Comment: "How to ask for a raise purely based off accomplishments" How is getting another job offer an accomplishment his company would be happy with?